# Class file name must end with .class exception in Java search

Tags: java, eclipse, search

I have a problem using the Java search function in Eclipse on a particular project.

When using the Java search on one particular project, I get an error message saying `Class file name must end with .class` (see stack trace below). This does not seem to be happening on all projects, just one particular one, so perhaps there's something I should try to get rebuilt?

I have already tried `Project -> Clean`... and Closing Eclipse, deleting all the built class files and restarting Eclipse to no avail.

The only reference I've been able to find on Google for the problem is at http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/eclipse/error-during-java-search.jspx, but unfortunately his solution (closing, deleting class files, restarting) did not work for me.

If anyone can suggest something to try, or there's any more info I can gather which might help track it's down, I'd greatly appreciate the pointers.

```
Version: 3.4.0
Build id: I20080617-2000
```

Also just found this thread - http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-20067.html - which indicates the same problem may occur when the project name contains a period. Unfortunately, that's not the case in my setup, so I'm still stuck.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file name must end with .class
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.getClassFile(PackageFragment.java:182)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.HandleFactory.createOpenable(HandleFactory.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1177)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:94)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:506)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:551)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.internalSearch(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.search(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:129)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameTypeProcessor.initializeReferences(RenameTypeProcessor.java:594)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameTypeProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameTypeProcessor.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.JavaRenameProcessor.checkFinalConditions(JavaRenameProcessor.java:45)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring.checkAllConditions(Refactoring.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper$Operation.run(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:709)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4650)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:92)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

### Update

Thanks McDowell, closing and opening the project seems to have fixed it (at least for now).

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with the classpath? Does your project reference any other projects or have an external classes or jars you are depending on?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Two more general-purpose mechanisms for fixing some of Eclipse's idiosyncrasies:

- Close and open the project
- Delete the project (but not from disk!) and reimport it as an existing project

Failing that, [bugs.eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__all__&product=JDT&content=Class+file+name+must+end+with+.class) might provide the answer.

If the workspace is caching something broken, you may be able to delete it by poking around in **workspace/.metadata/.plugins**. Most of that stuff is fairly transient (though backup and watch for deleted preferences).

Comment: Close & open worked for me, too. Previously I tried Project | Clean... on the whole workspace, but that didn't fix the problem. I'm wondering what project close & open does in addition to cleaning that project.

Comment: Closing and reopening my projects didn't help me :-( It seems like closing and reopening helps for some, but if it doesn't, you need to follow the advice by Olivier Dagenais

Answer (score 72):

Comment [#9 to bug 269820](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269820#c9) explains how to delete the search index, which appears to be the solution to a corrupt index whose symptoms are the dreaded

> An internal error occurred during: "Items filtering".
>   Class file name must end with .class

message box.

How to delete the search index:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/*.index
3. Delete <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/savedIndexNames.txt
4. Start Eclipse again

Comment: Minor typo.

2. Delete <workspace>.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core\*.index

Comment: This worked for me too. Found it here: http://u.nu/3aqy3 But it's the same procedure. ~Chris

Answer (score 7):

Got this error to the other day. Tried deleting the all .class-files and resources from my output folder manually. Didn't work. Restarted my computer (WinXP). Didn't work. Closed my project in Eclipse and opened it again. **Worked!!!** Hopes this solves someones problem out there. The search facilities and truly essential to Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered this issue recently, the below scenario worked for me.

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/*.index`
3. Delete `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/savedIndexNames.txt`
4. Start Eclipse again

Answer (score 3):

Closing the projects didn't do the trick for me. I started eclipse with the -clean flag and that worked for some reason.

Comment: clean option explanation: "if set to "true", any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these caches."

Answer (score 2):

Just

- Close project
- Clear manually output folder(s)
- Open project

(Eclipse 3.5 SR2, Build id: 20100218-1602)